# How to upload a file to a shared drive using unix?

Tags: samba

I have a requirement which says it should be able to upload and download a file from a Windows shared drive using UNIX.
How to approach that ? Should it be done using ftp or sftp ? Please explain.

Comment: You just need to mount windows shared drive in unix using samba, then just simply copy files using `cp` as local. take look at this link => https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Mounting_samba_shares_from_a_unix_client

Answer (score 2):

There is two requirements here:

- take a file from a drive shared from a windows machine
- upload a file (somewhere) using ftp/sftp

The first can be accomplised by using the **Samba** client for Unix, which allows you to mount a remote windows share on a Unix directory. Once that is done you can read the files (maybe also write, but that is not necessary).

For the second part you should go with `sftp`, as the "s" in there stands for secure. With the old `ftp` passwords can be sniffed. `sftp` is normally part of the `ssh` package. If possible you might want to look at using `scp`, the server that you are uploading to should support that as well. You should consider setting up passwordless login to the server using a public key (`ssh-keygen` and `ssh-copy-id`)

There is no need to setup a FTP server (or an SSH server) on the Unix machine that needs to do the uploading, isstalling Samba client and ssh (client) is enough.

Answer (score 1):

FTP uses PORT 21
SFTP uses PORT - whichever your SSH Daemon is listening to.

To get data/send use "STOR".
This could be used for shared drives as well as with server.